# Tomcat8 redirect http://8080 to https://8443 not working - instead https://8080

Tags: tomcat, redirect, web.xml, server.xml

We want to redirect `http://8080` to `https://8443` with Tomcat 8.
Unfortunately we come accross the situation that `http://server:8080`is redirected to  `https://server:8080` instead of `https://server:8443`.
I have updated server.xml as well as web.xml - showing below - However the port within the URL is not updated.

When the cache is cleaned (in any browser) then the first URL redirect works as expected while the second one fails again. However, when entering `http://server:8080/` as URL again it gets redirected to the wrong URL `https://server:8080/` again while the port does not change.

conf/server.xml

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443"
           maxPostSize="8388608" />

<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true"
           scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
           maxPostSize="8388608"
           ... Certificate settings...
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           compression="force"
           compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/javascript,text/css"/>
```

conf/web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>server</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Comment: Are you running Tomcat behind another web server like Apache HTTPD? If yes, check the redirect doesn't already happen there.

Comment: @user6708591 I have checked on the server and apperently there is no Apache HTTPD server running.